# Unix- Using Grep to get unmatched lines

Tags: unix, grep

I am new to unix. I want to grep the unmatched pattern from a file1 provided that the patterns are in the file2. The real files are having more than 1000 lines.

Example:

```
File1:
Hi(Everyone)
How(u)people(are)doing?
ThanksInadvance

File2:
Hi(Every
ThanksI
```

Required Result:

```
How(u)people(are)doing?
```

I want only the pattern to be used like ("Hi(Every") for the grep.It should return the unmatched line from file1.

Answer (score 6):

this line works for given example:

```
grep -Fvf file2 file1
```

The 3 options used above:

```
-F  makes grep do fixed-string match
-v  invert matching
-f  get patterns from file
```

Comment: Thanks Kent. It is working, but what if File1 contains a line like (Great("")) and File 2 contains a line like (Great. It is not working for above thing.

Comment: @Sibikrish it is working here.. `F` makes literal match instead of regex. so it should work.

Comment: Oops Sorry, ya it is working Thank you kent. But, It is matching the pattern irrespective of the position, Example: if file1: HelloHi(Everyone) file2: Hi(Every, grep -Fvf is removing that, any idea to grep it from beginning of a line alone.

Answer (score 1):

the Grep-Flag -v inverts the Grep-Command.

```
cat File1 |grep -v ("Hi(Every")
```

should return all Lines from File1 where ("Hi(Every") doesnt contains.

best regards,

Jan

Comment: Thanks Georg, but I need the code for the multiple lines in file2.